# $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=ex$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

We can verify that $x=125,162,343$ are the roots of equation $(x-105)(x-210)(x-315)=2584x$.
My question is,Could you find five positive integers $a,b,c,d,e$, which $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=ex$ has four positive integer roots?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relative questions: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331321/how-to-find-the-value-of-positive-integers-a-through-h-a-number-theory-or-alg)

Comment: Interesting problem.  How did you come up with it?

Comment: @Jonas Meyer:Someone asked in another forum,but she asked the equation of 7-power.I found some 3-power solutions,but can't find a higher power solution anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your attention, some one has offered me some examples:
$(x-5)(x-6)(x-16)(x-18)=84x,x=4,9,12,20;$
$(x-3)(x-4)(x-16)(x-22)=280x,x=2,8,11,24;$
$(x-3)(x-6)(x-32)(x-44)=2520x,x=2,11,24,48.$

Comment: As a supplement,he found a 5-power solution:$(x-4)(x-13)(x-17)(x-40)(x-50)=30240x$ has five integer roots,$x=5, 8, 25, 34, 52.$

Comment: An $8$-root solution exists: $(x - 2321) (x - 2263) (x - 2187) (x - 2163) (x - 2037) (x - 2001)(x - 1919) (x - 1909) = 17313885388800x$.

Comment: @Erick Wong: Great!How did you get this answer?

Comment: See my answer to the linked question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331321/how-to-find-the-value-of-positive-integers-a-through-h-a-number-theory-or-alg.

Comment: @Erick Wong:Thx,I have found it.

Comment: There is huge amount of rather small solutions: 
\begin{array}{|cc|c|} 
\hline \\ 
\{a,b,c,d;&e\} & \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\} \\ 
\hline \\ 
3,3,10,14;&48 &2,6,7,15\\ 
5,5,12,14;&20 &4,7,10,15\\ 
4,4,12,15;&36 &3,6,10,16\\
8,8,14,15;&8 &7,10,12,16\\
4,5,15,18;&120 &3,9,10,20\\
5,6,16,18;&84 &4,9,12,20\\
3,3,14,20;&108 &2,5,12,21\\
6,7,15,20;&60 &5,10,12,21\\
11,12,20,20;&20 &10,15,16,22\\ 
2,2,11,21;&200 &1,6,7,22\\
10,11,18,21;&24 &9,14,15,22\\ 
6,8,20,21;&144 &5,12,14,24\\
8,10,21,21;&84 &7,14,15,24\\
3,4,16,22;&280 &2,8,11,24\\
8,9,21,22;&60 &7,11,18,24\\ 
\cdots & \cdots 
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

**I.** A simple parametric solution can be given to,

$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = ex$$

such that $(a,b,c,d,e)$ and all four roots $x_i$ are all positive integers. This is,

\begin{align}
a &= 2n\\
b &= 2n+1\\
c &= (n+1)(n+3)\\
d &= 2(n+1)(n+2)\\ 
e &= n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)
\end{align}

with roots,

\begin{align}
x_1 &= n+1\\
x_2 &= 4(n+1)\\ 
x_3 &= n(n+2)\\
x_4 &= (n+3)(2n+1)\qquad\qquad
\end{align}

**II.** In general, this quartic problem can be solved by two quadratics. One must find six positive integers $(a,b,c,d,p,q)$ that obey,

$(a-p)(b-p)(c-pq)+p(a-p)(1-q)(c-dq)+p(1-q)(b-dq)(c-dq)=0\tag{1}$

a quadratic in $d$, such that,

$abc-pqx(a+b+c+d-p-dq-x)=0\tag{2}$

a quadratic in $x$ has positive integer roots. Then the four roots of,

$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = \frac{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)}{p}x\tag{3}$$

are $(p,dq,x_1, x_2)$ where the $x_i$ are the two roots of (2). If these four roots are integers, then the RHS of (3) obviously is also an integer.

*Proof*: Factor out $(x-p)$ from (3) and substituting $x = dq$ will yield (1). For the other two roots, eliminate $x$ between (2) and (3), and you will get also get (1).

**P.S.** Its quite easy for *Mathematica* to find small $(a,b,c,d,p,q)$ which led me to the parametrization above. However, one must avoid trivial solutions such as,

$$(a-p)(b-p)(c-p)(d-p)(a-dq)(b-dq)(c-dq)(q-1) = 0$$